# .passw hidden files in /etc

Tags: 10.04, server, security, rkhunter

Rkhunter reported me that it found hidden files in /etc:

```
Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.group.48239632746: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.passwd.13046384800: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.passwd.14350544901: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.passwd.16941124733: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.passwd.22154181091: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.passwd.48239632746: ASCII text
```

Should I be worried about it?

It seems those files are copies of the original passwd file....

Regards

Comment: Please check that they are really copies, and if they differ from the original passwd file, post how they differ. Also: can you post the output of `ls -l /etc/.passwd.*`?

Comment: ls -l /etc/.passwd.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7415 2011-05-05 22:29 /etc/.passwd.13046384800
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7341 2011-04-26 10:24 /etc/.passwd.14350544901
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7297 2011-04-18 17:51 /etc/.passwd.16941124733
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7297 2011-04-19 08:50 /etc/.passwd.22154181091
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7387 2011-04-19 15:25 /etc/.passwd.48239632746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question answered by OP in comments

> It seems to be the GUI I use. Nothing harmful.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to create users?  If you use GUI tools they might be creating a backup.  You should also take a look at output of:

```
ls -l /etc/.shadow*
```

Comment: No .shadow files at all. It seems to be the GUI I use. Nothing harmful.

Comment: Under normal circumstances there should be an /etc/shadow file.  Strange that the GUI doesn't back it up.